Why do lamps in circuit have potential difference but two points in cable without anything in the middle of it have no potential difference?

I'm preparing for my EE major, this is my starting point.

Shouldn't the title of your post end with "..have zero potential difference"

According to Ohm's law, the voltage drop $V$ over a component of resistance $R$ is given by
\begin{equation}
V = IR.
\end{equation}
where $I$ is the current. Since the resistance of the wire is negligible, the voltage drop will also be (practically) zero. A lamp, on the other hand, has a large resistance, so the voltage drop will be appreciable.

Unless the wire/conductor has no resistance it would have a tiny potential difference.  The lamp has high resistance as it consumes the energy and converts it to heat and or light thus giving a much larger potential difference.

Suppose you have a 100W lamp on a 100V supply, like the wall supply in the US. From $P=V^2/R$, you get that the lamp has a resistance of 100 Ω.
Now you go to buy a new power cable for your lamp.  The first search result has two 18-gauge wires, with a resistance per unit length of about 20 ohms per kilometer, or about 20 milli-ohms per meter.
So for a meter of cable, the voltage drop across each wire in the cable is five thousand times smaller than the voltage drop across the lamp.  Most electrical components have part-per-hundred level precision for nominal values.  Thermal drift stability and other tolerances are also in the part-per-hundred range.  There is also the problem that most meters have a contact resistance in the deci-ohm range; the contact resistance is a little different every time you reconnect your meter.  Milli-ohms are hard to measure.
The resistance in the cable isn't zero.  It's just small enough to ignore.
